# Window Active Directory React JS Auto Authentication

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, reactjs, active-directory

I am trying to get it so that when the user on the local network opens up the webpage it will log them in with their active directory username and password through a react js system with a C# API back-end. would react just say someone has connected on load and then send a message to the web api telling it to pull the user and authenticated it pushing that to the webpage for me to use as the login details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve by using common authentication/authorization protocol [OAuth 2](https://oauth.net/2/), which is commonly used.

for example google have different product like gmail, drive, doc etc which is hosted in different domain. But when you login in any of this domain, you don't require to login again in any of its product. it use **Signle Sign on** concept

Comment: I dont want to use anything like OAuth 2 if that can be helped

Comment: Any luck on this?